Role of Light in Time Domain
In the book "Molecular Spectroscopy" by Jeanne L.McHale is reported the demonstration of the relation between time and frequency domains, which I sketch here.
Starting from the definition of rate of transition as probability per unit of time we write the temporal derivative of the net energy as the sum over all initial and final states of these probability per unit time, weighed for the probability of population for the initial state and the quantum of energy of the transition:
$-\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{N}{V}\cdot \sum_{i,f}p_{i}w_{fi}$$\hbar$$\omega_{fi}$
Then, using Fermi's Golden Rule we explicit $w_{fi}$ as:
$-\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{N}{V}\cdot \sum_{i,f}(p_{i}-p_{f})\omega_{fi}|\langle{f|\vec{\mu}\cdot \vec{E}}|{i}\rangle|^2\delta{(\omega_{fi}-\omega)}$
From the properties of Dirac Delta and using Boltzmann distribution:
$-\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{N}{V}\omega(1-e^{-\frac{\hbar\omega}{k_{B}T}})\cdot \sum_{i,f}p_{i}|\langle{f|\vec{\mu}\cdot \vec{E}}|{i}\rangle|^2\delta{(\omega_{fi}-\omega)}$
This quantity is related to Spectral Intensity, which is simply:
$I_{(\omega)}=\sum_{i,f}p_{i}\omega_{fi}|\langle{f|\vec{\mu}\cdot \vec{E}}|{i}\rangle|^2\delta{(\omega_{fi}-\omega)}$
with some maths, in particular taking advantadge of the explicit form of Dirac Delta and the Schrodinger picture of QM and the closure property we arrive to
$I_{(\omega)}=\sum_{if}\int p_{i}\langle i|\mu_{(0)}\mu_{(t)}|i\rangle e^{-i\omega t}dt$
This is the demostration of the following important fact: the spectra in the frequency domain is the Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation functin of the dipole.
Despite the proof is quite simple to follow from a logical point of view, for me the result is quite difficult to understand when I have to go beyond the pure maths.
-This dipole, starting from the Fermi's Golden Rule, is the one responsible of the perturbation, the one which interact with the field.
So, is it a permament dipole, which is present also in absence of light? But in this way, does it mean that I can recover a spectra also without the field, because my sample is full of dipoles?
-More in general, looking only to the last integral, how can I recognize the role of light?
-What is this the dipole of the autocorrelation function, a transition dipole also if the different states of the bra and ket now are "collapsed" due to the closure property?
-why in the frequency domain the role of light through absorption and emission is explicit, while in time domain it seems so hidden?
